# When a multiclass demihuman reaches max-level in one class, does she need to keep splitting exp?

Tags: multi-classing, adnd-2e, character-advancement, experience-points

Suppose a multiclassed elf thief/wizard reaches max level in thief (14th, 880,000xp), but can still advance pretty far as wizard (with 880,000 she is a 12th-level wizard, and has still 5 more levels up to the 17th-level cap at 2,625,000xp).

Does she still need to split the earned exp in half (still counting rogue individual awards), or can she devote all exp (not counting the rogue individual awards anymore) to wizard?

DM has already ruled the cap is a hard one (and still allows for bonus cap for high stats, already factored above). No slow advancement, no wishing for allowing to progress in level.

Comment: Stop asking 2nd Edition questions! You're making me all nostalgic! :)

Comment: @Longspeak you recognize good things on how well do they age. It is like a single malt oak-barrel scotch. Or that french cheese i forgot the name... <cue in meme of monocle guy toasting>

Answer (score 6):

There is no answer in the Rules-As-Written of the Player's Handbook or the Dungeon Master's Guide, either in my 2nd Edition, or my 2nd Edition Revised books.

The ONLY reference I can find which hints at an answer within the rules is in the first paragraph of the section on Multi-Class characters (Page 44 of the 2nd Edition PHB, or Page 61 in the Revised edition; the text is identical):

> A multi-class character improves in two or more classes
>   simultaneously. His experience is divided equally between each class.

Based solely on this, a conservative interpretation of the rule would say yes, you still split the XP.

That said, I'd never do that. At a minimum, I'd have the player stop splitting into the capped class.

The multi-classing and level limit rules of AD&D have been subject to much debate and discussion which would be beyond the scope of this question, but which might be worth Googling.

Comment: That's how it works in AD&D 1e too (“Elf”, PHB p. 16), and I don't *think* they changed it…

Comment: I vaguely recall that, but haven't owned 1e books in a few years. :p But the 2e books were kind of a mess. I drove myself insane trying to find the level limits in the PHB until I remembered they're in the DMG for some darn reason.

Comment: Yes, the last line about "the GM has already dropped the hammer" was to curb the buzz about if level limits are a good thing or not, thanks a lot for going with it.

Comment: Once he hits the cap, he no longer "improves in two or more classes simultaneously"... so, there's an argument for full XP for the remaining class